# react-leaflet-draw allowIntersection does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I created a map with React-leaflet and React-leaflet-draw.
I need to prevent from line intersection when drawing a polyline or polygon and lines should not cross. So in EditControl I set allowIntersection to false, but there is a bug.
first here is my code:

`

```
      <FeatureGroup
        ref={(featureGroupRef) => onFeatureGroupReady(featureGroupRef)}
      >
        <EditControl
          position='topright'
          draw={{
            rectangle: false,
            polygon: {allowIntersection: false},
            polyline: {allowIntersection: false},
            circle: true, 
            circlemarker: false,
            marker: false,
          }}
          onCreated={onCreate}
          onDrawStart={onDrawStart}
          onDeleted={onDelete}
          onEditStart={onEdited}
          onDeleteStart={onDeleteStart}
        />

      </FeatureGroup>
```

`
the following screenshots show the problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see react-leaflet-draw does not prevent from intersection.

I searched through leaflet.draw and react-leaflet-draw demos and docs, I've noticed that its a problem with leaflet core API.

Actually leaflet can identify previous lines and prevent from intersection between this lines and the new line. but as you can see in third and fifth screenshots, can not detect intersection.

Well I thought about assigning a reference in my onCreate eventHandler and using some loops and also using `intersect()` method (according to leaflet docs), but according to the fact that it is a built-in issue with leaflet core, I guess it will not help.

Does anybody knows any way to fix intersection problem or any alternative way to detect and prevent from intersection ?

Comment: Sounds like you should open an issue with the leaflet-draw repo

Comment: Well, isn't there any js code that handles it ?